# Upload image to local folder in Webpack

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am having trouble uploading images locally.

I started a new React project using **create-react-app** and I wanted to know how do I upload images to my local folder.

My code (and project structure) right now:

`.
├── components
|   ├── PostForm.js
├── images
|   ├── img1.jpg
|   ├── img2.jpg`

In my **PostForm.js** I have a render method:

`<div className='col-md-12 form-group'>
        <input type="file" value={this.state.image} onChange=    {this.handleChangeImage}/>
    </div>`

Here is the input to upload files, **this.handleChangeImage** and **this.state** are showed below:

`this.state = {
        title: '',
        tag: '',
        description: '',
        image: ''
    };
    handleChangeImage = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            image: event.target.value
        });
    };`

I can only set image to a string as said by the console error.
So all I want is after getting the image from the `<input type='file' />` send it to **/images** folder.

Is that possible?

Thank you everybody!! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "send it to /images folder"? Note, `event.target.value` should return the fake path to the file, not the `File` instance.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that `event.target.value` will return a fake path.
What I need is that the actual `File` instance should be copied to **/images**

Comment: Reference the `File` instance `title: event.target.files[0]`

Comment: You need to use `express` for that, since you can't really edit the server config w/ `create-react-app`, you'll probably need to `eject`: meaning, convert to a local app (read `create-react-app` docs about this). I would suggest you first get it working from a bare HTML file served by express, then try to integrate that w/ react. Your question has way too many parts right now.

Comment: @guest271314
Thank you for the help!! :)
But I think I not doing it right! 
I tried somethink like this:
`this.state = {
    image: {}
};
handleChangeImage = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        image: event.target.files[0]
    });
};
`
but it keeps getting an error:
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`

Comment: @aarosil

hmm, I see, I didn't think it would be that complex... Ok, I am just trying to learn React, maybe I should focus on other stuff right now! Haha, thank you!! :)

Comment: Have minimal experience using `reactjs`. It is not possible to set a value at `FileList` object of `<input type="file">` element